# should I add new table to store new field in zencart db?

Tags: mysql, zen-cart

should I add new table to store new field in zencart db?
zencart original table

```
table : customers
customers_id | ...
1 | ...
2 | ...
```

now I need to add a new field for customer
I create a new table

```
table : customers_extra
customers_id | is_blogger
1 | 0
2 | 1
```

or directly created in the customers table

```
table: customers
customers_id | ... | is_blogger
1 | ... | 0
2 | ... | 1
```

which method should I use ? will add new table be worth to do ? will it slow down the query speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add it on to the Customers table.  It's a lot less work that way.  And no, you won't experience a slowdown from adding a one character field to a table like this.